# AIOserial problem: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, git, python-asyncio

I tried both cloning and downloading this repository from github: https://github.com/MightyDevices/aio-serial

When running this, I get the error: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

I also tried to do as the readme file says, but I can't manage to perform task 2 in readme which says:

git submodule update --init --recursive AIOSerial

I then get the error: error: pathspec 'AIOSerial' did not match any file(s) known to git

My question is kindly: Could someone here(with windows computer) try to download or clone this repository to check whether it works for you or not?

Some of you may wonder why I am trying to use AIOserial instead of pyserial-asyncio?  That is because I only have 1 computer with windows installed on it. And pyserial-asyncio support does not yet exist for windows.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What **exactly** have you tried to clone the repository? Both using `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/MightyDevices/aioserial AIOSerial` (as documented) and a simple `git clone https://github.com/MightyDevices/aioserial AIOSerial`, I cannot reproduce your problem

Comment: pyserial==3.4 is already installed on my system from before, so what i basically just did: 

'git  clone https://github.com/MightyDevices/aioserial AIOSerial'

according to a  friend of mine, did is all i need to do.